# sqldependency onchange firing in asp.net but asp.net Controls are not refreshing in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

`Sqldependency` onchange firing in `asp.net` successfully and I am able to get Updated Data in `Dataset` but when it Binds the `DataSet` to `Gridview` it doesn't Refresh Itself.

Furthermore, no `asp.net` Page Life Cycle event Fires when `SqlDependency` Event Fires.

```
                                                                                           protected void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
        dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;

        UpdatePanel1.Update();
        connstr = "server=66.226.75.158\\SQLEXPRESS;database=sqldependencydb;User id= sqldependencyuser01;Password= yewtee#123";
        string ssql = "select EmployeeID,FirstName from dbo.EmployeeList";
        if (connection == null)
            connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        if (command == null)
            command = new SqlCommand(ssql, connection);

        if (myDataSet == null)
            myDataSet = new DataSet();
        myDataSet.Clear();
        command.Notification = null;
        Label1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(myDataSet, "dbo.EmployeeList");
        GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet;
        GridView1.DataMember = "dbo.EmployeeList";
        GridView1.DataBind();



    }
```

Comment: I think you need to put `UpdatePanel1.Update();` after `GridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: is there is any solution about this ?

Comment: is there is any solution about this ? ??